# currentBuild() in jenkins

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-job-dsl

I have a DSL FreeStyleJob in jenkins. Let's say job/project named A is calling another job/project B as a post-build actions. I am making use of downstreamParameterized and passing currentBuild() paramaters as below

```
downstreamParameterized {
    trigger(B) {
        condition('SUCCESS')
            parameters {
                currentBuild()
            }
    }
}
```

And I know job/project B to be parameterized (Also DSL job). But **how do I accept currentBuild() as a parameter in B**. But I don't see any option related to it. Can anyone suggest?

[See this pic for parameter options](https://i.stack.imgur.com/49a8O.png)

I have already tried with predefined properties in job/project A and string parameters in job/project B and it works fine. But I don't want to follow this as there are many different type parameters in current build parameters.
I can't take file parameter options as both job workspace are different.

Comment: Is this a question about pipeline or job DSL? To me it doesn't look like pipeline.

Comment: It is related to DSL job.

Answer (score 0):

Solution is straight forward if the parameters are same for both the jobs. All you need to do is to declare the same set of parameters in JOB B as in JOB A. Jenkins will take care of passing the parameters to the downstream job.

**As long as you have the same set of parameters in both the jobs it should work.**

Reference :
Job 1 :
[image]

Job 2 :
[image]

Parameterized trigger in JOB 1
[image]

Thanks

Comment: I have already done the same. But the question here is how do you accept currentBuild of job 1 in job 2. and job 1 is not parameterized. It is triggered on PR open/changes and manually using test this please phrase configuration

Comment: If the upstream job is not parameterized then it is only possible if you pass the parameters while triggering the job in the post build step. The parameters that you are trying to pass to the downstream job, are the values available in the 1st job? I need to know what is the objective of the second job here?

Comment: The objective can be anything from doing an additional test run on success of upstream job independently and not combining the results with upstream. I have a checkout of same PR as upstream by passing parameters such as pullRequestId, sourceBranch... and so on upto 10 other parameters which are environment variables of current build. So if i pass currentBuild() instead of passing all 15 parameters, then how should i accept/receive this downStream job?
And will currentBuild() works with DSL jobs?